# Print information when changing pages

Tags: page-breaking, page-numbering, page, write

Can I print some information when generating a new page? For example, in the following example, I want to print "new page!" or page number in a txt file every time a new page is generated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newwrite\myoutfile
\immediate\openout\myoutfile=\jobname-myoutfile.txt
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can but note that TeX executes more than the content needed to draw a page before actually outputting the page, so what are you really trying to do?